# import Android code in xamarin or convert to C# Android

Tags: android, xamarin

Is there any solution to convert java based Android code to C# based Android code or can we import java Android code in xamarin?

Answer (score 2):

There is a detailed answer in [Porting Java to C#](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/java_integration_overview/porting_java_to_csharp/) Xamarin guide

> The second porting methodology is to try and automate the process by
>   using a code converter, such as Sharpen. Sharpen is an open source
>   converter from Versant that was originally used to port the code for
>   db4o from Java to C#. db4o is an object-oriented database that Versant
>   developed in Java, and then ported to .NET. Using a code converter may
>   make sense for projects that must exist in both languages and that
>   require some parity between the two.